# Polynomials over a finite field - avaerage value

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Need to prove that if
$$ 
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{q^{n}}\sum_{\begin{array}[t]{c}
f\textrm{ monic}\\
\deg(f)=n
\end{array}}h(f) 
$$
exists, it's equal to:
$$ 
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1+q+q^{2}\ldots+q^{n}}\sum_{\begin{array}[t]{c}
f\textrm{  monic}\\
\deg(f)\leq n
\end{array}}h(f) 
$$

Notations: $ q $ is the number of elements in the finie field, and $ h $ is a function on the set of monic polynomials.

Comment: Usually, you are supposed to show that you searched a bit and explain at least what you did, and what is blocking you.

Comment: This function is not off-topic at all. Everything needed to answer it is stated in the question, so I do not see why it is put on hold as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $ c_n = \sum_{\begin{array}[t]{c}
f\textrm{ monic}\\
\deg(f)=n
\end{array}}h(f)$ and $ d_n = \sum_{\begin{array}[t]{c}
f\textrm{ monic}\\
\deg(f)\leq n
\end{array}}h(f)$. You obviously have $d_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i$. Now, you know that $\frac{c_n}{q^n}$ has a limit, and you want to show that $\frac{d_n}{1+\ldots+q^n} = \frac{c_0 + \ldots + c_n}{1+\ldots+q^n}$ has one. This is implied by the [Stoltz-Cesaro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) with $b_n = 1+\ldots+q^n$ and $a_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i$.

Comment: I Tried to prove it directly, totally forgot Stolz theorem. Thank you !